# git: "not something we can merge" across all repos

Tags: git, github

I'm getting this error on all my local repositories when I try to pull my upstream master branch.

```
⬡ >> git pull origin master
From github.com:xyz/outland
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
merge: welcome - not something we can merge
```

It will fetch, but not merge the remote branch and I get this even after I check out a fresh copy of each repository. The repos are completely independent of each other so it must be a global issue to my computer, however I can't figure out what I did to get in this state.

git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47) on a 15" macbook retina

Comment: What's in the `FETCH_HEAD` file in the git directory, at that point?

Comment: @torek FETCH_HEAD contains a revset pointing to the tip of the upstream branch I'm trying to pull.

Comment: OK, that's what it should have.  So something else is printing the "welcome" message.  For some reason when the `pull` script runs `eval "exec $eval"`, with `$eval` set to `git-merge ... HEAD $merge_head`, `$merge_head` is expanding to `welcome ...` instead of just the rev from FETCH_HEAD.  That in turn implies something going wrong with either `sed` or `tr`.  See the `git-pull` script in wherever your git-core directory is.

Comment: Wow - this is exactly it. I had accidentally written a script called tr and put it in a directory that was in front of /usr/bin in my $PATH. Thanks a ton.